# How to inject basic PHP function into HTML body of a PHPmailer email?

Tags: php, html, forms, phpmailer

I am pretty new to backend PHP developement... I know how to capture posted data into PHP variables and inject those variables into the body of my HTML email. However, I don't know how to implement a PHP "foreach" function inside my HTML.

**The goal being the following:**

Use PHPmailer to send an HTML email using a simple PHP "foreach" function to capture input data and paste them into the body of the HTML email.

I have simplified my problem: I would like to use a for each function to capture all input with the name attribute "FRUIT" and inject their respective data-attribute and values inside the body of my HTML.

The **expected behaviour** would be to reveive an email which body would look like this:

apple: 1

banana: 2

here is my simplified **HTML** form:

```
   <form id="form" action="(action.php) method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="FRUIT[]" data-attribute="apple" value="1">
      <input type="text" name="FRUIT[]" data-attribute="banana" value="2">
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

here is my simplified **PHP** action script:

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require '/home/furtbswy/public_html/PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php';
require '/home/furtbswy/public_html//PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php';
require '/home/furtbswy/public_html/PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php';


$mail = new PHPMailer(false);

try {

    $from = 'xxxxxxh@gmail.com';
    $to = $_POST['EMAIL'];
    $fruits= '';
    foreach ($_POST['FRUIT'] as $key => $value) {
      $fruits.= "$key: $value <br>";
    }
    $message = '
        <html>
            <body>
            Fruits: ' . $fruits. '
            </body>
        </html>
        ';

    // PHPmailer setup
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->Username = $from;
    $mail->Password = 'xxxxxx';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;

    // recipients
    $mail->setFrom($from);
    $mail->addAddress($to);

    // content
    $mail->Subject = 'confirmation';
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Body = $message;
    $mail->send();

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
?>
```

Comment: `data-*` attributes are not included in form submits.

Comment: Forms default to a GET method if POST isn't specifically implied.

Comment: @PatrickQ, thank you Patrick. All right, I have edited my post. Let's say I wish to get the name and value of my inputs inside my HTML email. Is there a way to do that with this basic foreach PHP function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `foreach` as an expression. Append to the variable in the loop:

```
$result = '';
foreach ($_POST['NAME'] as $key => $value) {
    $result .= "$key: $value <br>";
}
```

Comment: I was about to type this, then second guessed it and thought maybe I was going to learn a new way to use foreach, went to look, came back, and here you are. I know you don't know me, but I see you all over here @Barmar. Thanks for all you contribute, even if this comment ends up removed as non-constructive...
Any chance you know why php doesn't implement foreach to be used this way?

Comment: In general, control statements can't be used as expressions. It has functions like `array_map()` and `implode()` that can be used to do this.

Comment: You can't use `$variable = if ...`, you have to use the `? :` conditional operator.

Comment: Thanks alot @Barmar, that worked like a charm ! I will now have to dig deeper and see how to get the data-attribute as $key instead of the name attribute. I have updated my post to reflect your solution sofar.

Comment: You could put the attribute in the names: `name="NAMES[apple]"`. Then you'll get `$key = "apple"`